# Heap corruption by strings

Tags: c++, string, char, heap-corruption

Lets say I have this piece of code

```
void someFunction(args..) {
 char array[4];
 array[0] = 'a';
 array[1] = 'b';
 array[2] = 'c';
 array[3] = 'd';
}
```

Basically, what I'm getting at is that there is no '\0' at the end of the array.
When we leave this function, the array[] is de-allocated - right? Can the fact that there is no '\0' sign at the end cause heap corruption? What if functions like these occur often? Is it the same if I do this:

```
void someFunction(args..) {
 char* array = new char[4];
 array[0] = 'a';
 array[1] = 'b';
 array[2] = 'c';
 array[3] = 'd';
 //and now i dont call 
 //delete array;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help ! :)

Comment: Why are you using C style strings? And this would very much depend on what you do with the `array` as it is.

Comment: _"Basically, what I'm getting at is that there is no '\0' ..."_ Why would you expect one, if you don't put one there? Define your array as `char array[5];` and put `array[4] = '\0';` for both of your code samples! That has nothing to do with stack or heap.

Answer (score 3):

No, neither case will cause heap corruption.

The terminating null character is used to signal the end of a string to library functions.  You are not using any library functions here.

In the first case, the array is allocated on the stack and you give an exact size (4).  When the function is called the stack pointer will be decremented enough to add room for this variable, and when it returns the stack pointer will be incremented the same amount.  The actual contents of the array (including the presence or absence of any null terminating character) has absolutely no effect on this process.

Your second case will cause a memory leak, but still won't cause heap corruption because -- again -- you don't use the pointer with any library functions that expect it.

Comment: Thanks! If I have a lot of places where I allocated like this:
char *array = new char[...]
basically, a lot of leaks, would that cause my application to write to memory behind end of heap ?

Comment: @Alek988Alek No, it just means that the memory cannot be reclaimed by the operating system until your program terminates.  I would strongly suggest you use `std::string` unless you have a specific reason not to, as it will manage these memory allocations for you automatically.

Comment: Another follow up, I'm really losing my mind here, if i declare the function like:
void function(char*)

and it does something with its argument;
then i call it like this:
char array[] { "abcd" };
function(array);

that WILL cause havoc, right ?

i should call it like this: function(&array), right ?

Comment: @Alek988Alek Well, first note that the syntax `char array[] { "abcd" };` only works in C++11 and does the same thing as the C-compatible `char array[] = "abcd";` so I would suggest using the `=` syntax instead of the `{}` syntax.  Secondly, no, this will not cause havoc because the null terminator is part of the string literal and the language will copy that as part of the initialization.  (Note that `sizeof(array) == 5`.)  `function(array)` is fine because the array will decay into a pointer type automatically.

Answer (score 2):

> When we leave this function, the `array[]` is de-allocated - right?

Yes. Like any automatic variable, it's destroyed when the program leaves its scope.

> Can the fact that there is no '\0' sign at the end cause heap corruption?

It won't corrupt anything unless you write an element that's out of range; perhaps by passing it to a function like `strcpy` which can write an arbitrary number of characters to it. But simply creating it, writing within its range, and destroying it won't do any harm. (In any event, it's unlikely to corrupt the heap, since it's on the stack).

The terminator is only needed by code that interprets the array contents as a C-style string. There's no requirement for arrays to be terminated in general, and it's fairly unusual to use terminated string in C++, which has the much more convenient `std::string` type.

> What if functions like these occur often?

No problem. Each time, the array is created on the function's stack frame, which is released when the function returns.

> Is it the same if I do this: [`new` with no `delete`]

That causes a memory leak, since you're allocating a dynamic array but never freeing it. Again, it won't corrupt anything, since you're only writing within the array bounds; but if you keep leaking, then eventually you'll run out of memory.

Comment: someone beat you to the answer, but thanks regardless, of course ! :)